# Excel - Take numbers which contains specific String

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Assuming my column is A:

I have  these Excel columns:

```
#ACA17234=5;1'Some Message'
#ACA17232<5;1'Some Message'
#ACA17238_2_5;1'Some Message'
#ACA17239_2_5;1'Some Message'
#ACA17237_2_5;1'Some Message'
```

I want to a Excel function that takes exactly five numbers which gave me ;
17234,17232,17238,17239,17237

Edit:

```
((#ACA18655=0)&(#AGV32=6)&(#ACA18702=1))?((#FC1000ACA18701$3)?'Eksper ücretini onaylayınız..':''):((#ACA18540>0)?((#ACA18540$#ACA18541)?'Otoanalizden aktarılan ve dosya üzerinde atalı olan AT kodu farklı !!':''):'')
```

Not all rows are started with `#ACA` I have rows like these

Comment: so you want to extract 17234 from the string #ACA17234XXXXX. and you can do this position based skip first 4 and take 5 chars

Comment: yes no need to take after these five digits thanks

Comment: not all rows are start with #ACA so i need to extract 5 digits after #ACA

Comment: so you only need to extract if the row begins with #ACA

Comment: I dont think you can solve this puzzle with pure excel, think you need some coding with VBA macro / code

Answer (score 0):

you can use below formula, which find a text in the middle of a string. skips first 5 chars, then takes 5 chars

```
=MID(A2,5,5)
```

Comment: Thanks but where i put my ACA in this formula. I know nothing about Excel sorry

Comment: do you only want to take the chars if the row start with #ACA

Comment: uhm i edited the question some of are start different so i need to catch ACA's in the middle of the strings anywhere

Comment: and there could me more the one ?

Comment: Yeah i have 400+ rows and the ACA's can be anywhere in the cell

Comment: and there can be more ACA in one row?

Answer (score 0):

To find number with five digits from cell A1 you can use the following formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("0"&REPT("1",5)&"0",CONCAT(0+(ISNUMBER(-MID(" "&A1&" ",ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)+2)),1))+0)))),"",MID(A1,FIND("0"&REPT("1",5)&"0",CONCAT(0+(ISNUMBER(-MID(" "&A1&" ",ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)+2)),1))+0))),5))
```

To search for other number of digits change the three occurrences of number `5` to your desired digits count in the formula.